# AWS S3 policy size limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I have a long and still growing policy within one of my S3 buckets. I want to check the total length to see, if the policy may hit the [20KB hard limit of AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-iam-policies.html) anytime soon.

I did following in my js console:

```
policy = <text copied from s3 bucket policy>
JSON.stringify(policy).length
> 28941
```

The policy works even though I should be over the limit. How can this be? How can I reliably check the policy size in an AWS approved manner and see, how many characters are still left?

I did following:

- checked the AWS docs
- counted the characters myself

Comment: Maybe it removes whitespace?

Comment: JSON.stringify removes all whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import json

def normalize_policy(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            normalize_policy(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for i, item in enumerate(value):
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    normalize_policy(item)
                elif isinstance(item, str):
                    if key == "AWS" and item.startswith("arn:aws:iam::"):
                        if item.endswith(":root"):
                            value[i] = item.split(':')[4]
                        elif ":role/" in item or ":user/" in item:
                            value[i] = 21*'X'
            if len(value) == 1:
                data[key] = value[0]
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            if key == "AWS" and value.startswith("arn:aws:iam::"):
                if value.endswith(":root"):
                    data[key] = value.split(':')[4]
                elif ":role/" in value or ":user/" in value:
                    data[key] = 21*'X'

input_data = sys.stdin.read()
s3_policy = json.loads(input_data)

normalize_policy(s3_policy)

normalized_policy = json.dumps(s3_policy).replace(" ", "")

policy_size = len(normalized_policy)

print(policy_size)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35728742)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any S3 API that can simply return the size of a bucket policy.

You can compute the size of a bucket policy as a JSON object, just like any other JSON object. It looks like you are using JavaScript. In JavaScript, the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property of a string contains the length of the string in UTF-16 code units, not the size of the string in bytes.

Getting the size of a JSON object depends on the JS runtime you are using. For example, if you are using node.js or a modern browser, you can convert your JSON to an [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) and infer the size from the length of that array (in `Uint8Array` each item is a 1 byte unsigned integer).

```js
const obj = JSON.stringify(myJson);
const arr = new TextEncoder().encode(obj); // returns Uint8Array containing UTF-8 encoded text.
const sizeInBytes = arr.length;
const sizeInKB = arr.length / 1024;
```

Answer (score 1):

After contacting AWS support on this it turned out that:

1. 20kB policy size limit is still valid and enforced.
2. AWS is doing some policy normalizations which reduce the total size of the policy, so the total size of the policy in characters may be bigger then what `JSON.stringify(policy)` may report.
3. To my understanding there are no means to calculate the size of the normalized policy besides contacting AWS S3 support. If `JSON.stringify(policy).length < 20kB` then you are safe, else consider a workaround soon.
4. Using multiple S3 Access Points is one of the ways how to bypass the policy size limits.